# How can i get average between first row and row before current row[i] in each group of data frame for specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, average

for example i have loop in data frame, in each group-by(id) when i am in current row[i] i want to get average of all previous rows in same group

eg// in (a) group when i am in row 4 i want to get average for (20,18,19)
when i am in row 5  i want to get average for (20,18,19,20)

and so on for all rows and groups in data frame

| id | total |
| --- | --- |
| a | 20 |
| a | 18 |
| a | 19 |
| a | 20 |
| a | 21 |
| a | 15 |
| b | 13 |
| b | nan |
| b | 15 |
| b | 5 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`expanding()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) for this. Groupby id, use expanding to get a running output, then mean() for the average:

```
df.groupby('id').expanding().mean().reset_index()

  id      total
0  a  20.000000
1  a  19.000000
2  a  19.000000
3  a  19.250000
4  a  19.600000
5  a  18.833333
6  b  13.000000
7  b  13.000000
8  b  14.000000
9  b  11.000000
```

To get the average up to but not including each row, you can just group again, and shift these numbers by 1. Full line of code:

```
out = df.groupby('id').expanding().mean().reset_index().groupby('id').shift(1)

   level_1  total
0      NaN    NaN
1      0.0  20.00
2      1.0  19.00
3      2.0  19.00
4      3.0  19.25
5      4.0  19.60
6      NaN    NaN
7      6.0  13.00
8      7.0  13.00
9      8.0  14.00
```

Then you can increase level_1 by 1, and merge this back to the index of the original dataframe to get the desired result:

```
out['level_1'] = out['level_1'] + 1
(df.reset_index().merge(out, left_on='index', right_on='level_1',
                        how='left', suffixes=[None, ' average'])[['id', 'total', 'total average']])


  id  total  total average
0  a   20.0            NaN
1  a   18.0          20.00
2  a   19.0          19.00
3  a   20.0          19.00
4  a   21.0          19.25
5  a   15.0          19.60
6  b   13.0            NaN
7  b    NaN          13.00
8  b   15.0          13.00
9  b    5.0          14.00
```

Full code:

```
out = df.groupby('id').expanding().mean().reset_index().groupby('id').shift(1)
out['level_1'] = out['level_1'] + 1
df = (df.reset_index().merge(out, left_on='index', right_on='level_1',
                        how='left', suffixes=[None, ' average'])[['id', 'total', 'total average']])
```

Comment: please what is mean (1) in expand ,?

Comment: @iimm It is just the "Minimum number of observations in window required to have a value; otherwise, result is np.nan", if you were to put a bigger number in there, it would return nan until it has that many numbers to calculate with. Basically it means it will begin calculating the mean even with just 1 number

Comment: 1 is the default, you could take it out and just have expanding(), it will be the same

Comment: please if i want to make loop in data frame : for i in range(0,len(df)): and check if df['total'][i]< mean(for previous rows of [total] in same group) , so will put in anew column [status] the word 'no', else put 'yes; how to make it please?

Comment: @iimm You should really ask that in a new question.  If my answer helped you solve the question asked here, please click the tick to the left to accept it, and upvote

Comment: it's ok this statement very useful, but please i just need  the value in current index row not included in mean, for example row of index(1) must be 20, row of index(9) must be 14, row of index(8) must be 13, and so on for all

Comment: but this take the current value in mean, i want average for previous rows except current value in every time,  that what i write in my question

Comment: @iimm I've updated my answer, I hope this is now what you were after?

Comment: this error appear:  KeyError: "['total average'] not in index"

Comment: @iimm runs fine for me, does your example df in the question have the same column names as the one you're using? and no spaces or anything?

Comment: there is no column named 'total average' in original data frame.

Comment: @iimm I know, my code creates one using the 'total' column. When it merges, it creates another column from the 'total' column in the out df and adds the suffix ' average' to the end.

Comment: when i want to print result data frame , write this print(df)
? use (df)??

Comment: my final line of code will show the final dataframe as an output, you will need to assign this to df (or whatever you want to call it). You can do either

Comment: yes, now its ok thank you so much

Comment: please, if i want to keep first value in each group  in 'total' the same in ' total average' in instead of 'nan', what should do,?

Answer (score -1):

you can use `expanding()`to define a calculation window and `groupby()` to group by your indexes, and then reset your indexes to recover the original shape of your dataframe like :

```
df = df.groupby('id').expanding(1).mean()

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.drop('level_1', axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

output:

```
  id      total
0  a  20.000000
1  a  19.000000
2  a  19.000000
3  a  19.250000
4  a  19.600000
5  a  18.833333
6  b  13.000000
7  b  13.000000
8  b  14.000000
9  b  11.000000
```

Comment: please if i want to make loop in data frame : for  i in  range(0,len(df)):
and check if df['total'][i]< mean(for previous rows of [total] in same group) , so will put in anew column [status] the word 'no', else put 'yes;  how to make it please?

Comment: it's ok this statement very useful, but please i just need  the value in current index row not included in mean, for example row of index(1) must be 20, row of index(9) must be 14, row of index(8) must be 13, and so on for all

Comment: use this instead of the .drop I used  (replace the line) : `df.drop(['level_1', 'id], axis=1, inplace=True)`